# Parsing colnames text string as expression in R

Tags: r, parsing, expression

I am trying to create a large number of data frames in a for loop using the "assign" function in R.  I want to use the colnames function to set the column names in the data frame. The code I am trying to emulate is the following:

```
county_tmax_min_df <- data.frame(array(NA,c(length(days),67))) 
colnames(county_tmax_min_df) <- c('Date',sd_counties$NAME) 
county_tmax_min_df$Date <- days
```

The code I have so far in the loop looks like this:

```
file_vars = c('file1','file2')
days <- seq(as.Date("1979-01-01"), as.Date("1979-01-02"), "days")

f = 1
for (f in 1:2){
  assign(paste0('county_',file_vars[f]),data.frame(array(NA,c(length(days),67))))
}
```

I need to be able to set the column names similar to how I did in the above statement.  How do I do this?  I think it needs to be something like this, but I am unsure what goes in the text portion.  The end result I need is just a bunch of data frames.  Any help would be wonderful.  Thank you.

```
expression(parse(text = ))
```

Comment: What's the nature of the `days` object? Can you post example with the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the names *within* assign, like that:

```
file_vars = c('file1', 'file2')
days <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("1979-01-01"), to = as.Date("1979-01-02"), by = "days")

for (f in seq_along(file_vars)) {
    assign(x = paste0('county_', file_vars[f]),
           value = {
               df <- data.frame(array(NA, c(length(days), 67)))
               colnames(df) <- paste0("fancy_column_", 
                                      sample(LETTERS, size = ncol(df), replace = TRUE))
               df
           })
}
```

When in `{}` you can use `colnames(df)` or `setNames` to assign column names in any manner desired. In your first piece of code you are referring to `sd_counties` object that is not available but the generic idea should work for you.